# Maximization given constraints

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

How does one maximize the following equation?
$(a-c)(b-c)(a-b)$ given that $-n \le c < b < a \le n$ for some value of $n$

So far, I have attempted to do this using AM-GM and got $\frac{64}{27}n^3$ but I don't think this is correct as some of the values of a, b, and c can be negative and when I tried to find the actual values which satisfied the max value found it gave me a contradiction.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE. Could you give us more information about the problem. Where does it come from? What do you know about it? What have you tried?

Comment: What is your equality case for 64/27? Or is that just an upper bound that you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $ 2n \geq (a - c) = ( a - b ) + (b - c )$.
All terms in parenthesis are non-negative, and AM-GM applies.

Hence, conclude that

> $ (a-c)(a-b)(b-c) \leq 2n \times n \times n = 2n^3$.

Clearly, this can be achieved with $ a = n, b = 0, c = -n$.